Can extends [any, any] but not generic which is exactly [any, any]
I'm trying to extract known part of a tuple without loosing labels even with rest tuple, and came over with a solution
type Data = [a: 1, b: 2, ...c: 3[]]

type TestType1<T extends any[]> = 
    T extends [...infer R extends [any, any], ...any[]] ? R : never
type test1 = TestType1<Data>
//   ^? type test1 = [a: 1, b: 2] Works as intended

But when i pass the mask as a generic while it's value is still [any, any] it loses info:
type TestType2<T extends any[], Mask extends any[] = [any, any]> = 
    T extends [...infer R extends Mask, ...any[]] ? R : never
type test2 = TestType2<Data>
//   ^? type test2 = [any, any] ??? expected [a: 1, b: 2] as in test1

Firstly i do not understand why it breaks, but then is they're a typo error ? can it be achieved ?
Playground link

Did log an issue as the playground provided earlier works just fine with typescript version 5.3.3, therefor this seems to be a regression bug
the issue

This is a simplification as Mask is supposed to change on conditions.
Side note I tested on the playground with typescript version 5.3.3 and it wotks just fine.
It does break since typescript version 5.4.5. It looks like a regression bug - should I open an issue on github do you reckon @jcalz ?

Did post an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/60299

I need Mask to be generic as Mask is not set in stone like the example and can change with conditions
The only consraint on it is for it to be a tuple of any's without a rest

@jcalz example of use - it's set up on version 5.3.3 so it works - but if you change the version to 5.4 or more it then breaks
